# Calling class methods from different class

Tags: python

Just learning multi-level inheritance. This code is running fine:

```py
class Base_1:
    def base_1(self):
        print("Base Class 1")

class Base_2:
    def base_2(self):
        print("Base Class 2")

class Derive(Base_1,Base_2):
    def call(self):
        print("I am derive from {0} {1}".format(Base_1.base_1(self),Base_2.base_2(self)))


obj=Derive()
obj.call()
```

The actual code was:

```py
class Base_1:
    def base_1(self):
        print("Base Class 1")

class Base_2:
    def base_2(self):
        print("Base Class 2")

class Derive(Base_1,Base_2):
    def call(self):
        print("I am derive from {0} {1}".format(Base_1.base_1(),Base_2.base_2()))


obj=Derive()
obj.call()
```

Error shown by the actual code:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 12
      9         print("I am derive from {0} {1}".format(Base_1.base_1(),Base_2.base_2()))
     11 obj=Derive()
---> 12 obj.call()

Cell In[9], line 9, in Derive.call(self)
      8 def call(self):
----> 9     print("I am derive from {0} {1}".format(Base_1.base_1(),Base_2.base_2()))

TypeError: Base_1.base_1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

After adding `self` parameter it is running but I don't know why. Can anyone please tell why adding the `self` parameter solves my issue ?

Comment: By default methods in a class are instance methods. To make a method a class method, you should add @classmethod before the definition. Adding this makes the code run fine but I assume the intended behavior is to return "Base Class 1" (and 2) instead of returning it in your base classed.

Comment: When accessing a method like this: `Base_1.base_1`, that is, `<classname>.<methodname>`, you obtain the 'unbound' method. This needs all the parameters passing in. Since your class `Derive` derives from the other classes you have access to these methods through `self`, so the better option is like: `self.base_1()`

Answer (score 1):

To have `self` "auto-passed" as the first argument, you need to call the methods like instance methods:

```py
print("I am derive from {0} {1}".format(self.base_1(),self.base_2()))
```

note that in your case, both methods print, but return None, if you want it to behave as you probably intended, consider returning the string instead of printing it

Comment: so to call instance method from another class we need to use self because i thought i have already mention self in method why i need to mention self keyword again while calling

Comment: You never create an instance of `Base_1` and `Base_2` - `self` only gets passed automagically _when there's an object_ - not when calling a method directly in a class. However, you can decorate the method with `@classmethod` to get the class itself automagically passed as the first argument (usually named `cls` instead of `self`) if you don't need access to an actual instance in `base_1` and `base_2`. If you want to call them on the _instance_ as it seems as you want to, refer to the instance (i.e. `self`) as shown by @Adam.Er8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call method of some class without create instance of its class, you can set method as static or class method.

```
class Base_1:
    @classmethod
    def base_1(cls):
        print("Base Class 1")
class Base_2:
    @classmethod
    def base_2(cls):
        print("Base Class 2")
class Derive(Base_1,Base_2):
    def call(self):
        print("I am derive from {0} {1}".format(Base_1.base_1(),Base_2.base_2()))

obj=Derive()
obj.call()
```

this code is not tested.

The parameter "cls" for method "base_1" and "base_2" means class itself.